# Create a Note object in Ivanti's HEAT API in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've been tasked with creating a 'Note Business Object' using Ivanti HEAT API in C#. This is what I tried to create:

1. Make CreateNote method with this body:

```
public Note CreateNote(ServiceRequest parent, string category, string summary, string notes)
{
    Logger.Verbose($"Heat.CreateNote({parent}, {category}, {summary}, {notes}");

    String type = "Journal#Note";

    List<ObjectCommandDataFieldValue> dataFields = new List<ObjectCommandDataFieldValue>()
    {
        new ObjectCommandDataFieldValue()
        {
            Name = "Category",
            Value = category,
        },
        new ObjectCommandDataFieldValue()
        {
            Name = "Summary",
            Value = summary,
        },
        new ObjectCommandDataFieldValue()
        {
            Name = "Notes",
            Value = notes
        },
        new ObjectCommandDataFieldValue()
        {
            Name = "ParentLink_Category",
            Value = "ServiceReq"
        },
        new ObjectCommandDataFieldValue()
        {
            Name = "ParentLink_RecID",
            Value = parent.RecID
        },
        new ObjectCommandDataFieldValue()
        {
            Name = "Status",
            Value = "Logged"
        },
        new ObjectCommandDataFieldValue()
        {
            Name = "CreatedDateTime",
            Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        },
        new ObjectCommandDataFieldValue()
        {
            Name = "LastModDateTime",
            Value = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        },
    };

    return new Note(CreateObject(type, parent, dataFields), this);
}
```

2. Make the CreateObject method to create a Business Object:

```
private WebServiceBusinessObject CreateObject(String type, WebServiceBusinessObject Parent, List<ObjectCommandDataFieldValue> variables)
{
    Logger.Verbose($"Entered Heat.CreateObject({Parent}, {variables})");
    ObjectCommandData data = new ObjectCommandData();

    data.ObjectType = type;

    data.Fields = variables.ToArray();

    FRSHEATIntegrationCreateBOResponse response = Client.CreateObject(SessionKey, TenantId, data);
    Logger.Verbose($"Soap response status: {response.status}");
    Logger.Verbose($"Soap response Exception: {response.exceptionReason}");
    Logger.Verbose($"Soap response recId:{response.recId}");
    Logger.Verbose($"Soap response obj:{response.obj}");

    Logger.Verbose($"Exited Heat.CreateObject() => {response.obj}");
    return response.obj;
}
```

3. Test it by using following call in program

```
Note newNote = Heat.CreateNote(SR, $"TestNote - {DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy - HH:mm")}", "Test Note", "This test note has been created through the API");

Console.WriteLine(newNote.RecID);
```

But then I get this exception:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> obj was null.

I'm really not that familiar with the Ivanti HEAT API and there's next to no clear information around it.

There's an example of creating a Task in the library and this one works completely.

This is the stack trace:
[image: stack trace error code null]

This is the method where it fails (in WebServiceBusiness):

```
public WebServiceBusinessObjectExtented(WebServiceBusinessObject obj, Heat Heat)
{
    this.Alias = obj.Alias; <-- null ref ex
    this.BusinessObjectName = obj.BusinessObjectName;
    this.FieldValues = obj.FieldValues;
    this.RecID = obj.RecID;
    this.TableRef = obj.RecID;
    this.Heat = Heat;

    InitializeCommandDate();
}
```

Comment: You at least need to share a stack trace. Is the null reference in your code, the service client or some other library?

Comment: @HasaniH I editted my post.

Comment: I assume you get obj from your CreateObject method? What do your logs say? Is there a response.exceptionReason? What's the response.status?

Comment: @HasaniH Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in AG.HEAT.dll
**obj** was null.